# different explanation

Tags: php

The code

```
$global_obj = null;
class my_class
{
       var $value;
       function my_class()
       {
               global $global_obj;
               $global_obj = &$this;
       }
}
$a = new my_class;
$a->my_value = 5;
$global_obj->my_value = 10;
echo $a->my_value;
```

echoes 5, not 10.

"Upon first examination, it would seem that the constructor of my_class stores a reference to itself inside the $global_obj variable. Therefore, one would expect that, when we later change the value of $global_obj->my_value to 10, the corresponding value in $a would change as well. Unfortunately, the new operator does not return a reference, but a copy of the newly created object."

I still don't understand it, so can anyone please explain it differently, and help me understand?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure why this is the way it works, but, if you remove the `&` in front of `$this` while assigning it to your global variable, it will work.

To illustrate that, the following portion of code :

```
$global_obj = null;
class my_class
{
   public $my_value;
   public function __construct()
   {
        global $global_obj;
        $global_obj = $this;
   }
}
$a = new my_class;
$a->my_value = 5;

$global_obj->my_value = 10;
echo $a->my_value;
```

Gives the following output :

```
10
```

Here are the differences with your code :

- I remove the `&` before `$this` : with PHP 5, there is no need for that, when working with objects
- I translated the code to *real PHP 5* :

  - `__construct` for the [constructor](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php)
  - use `public`/`protected`/`private`, and not `var` for [properties](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php)

As a sidenote, the code you posted should have given you the following warning :

```
Strict standards: Creating default object from empty value
```

Notes :

- I'm using PHP 5.3.2
- `E_ALL` doesn't include `E_STRICT` *([source](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php))*

---

**EDIT after some more searching :**

Going through the [**References Explained**](http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.references.php) section of the PHP manual, and, more specifically the [**What References Do**](http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php) page, there is a warning given that says *(quoting)* :

> If you assign a reference to a
>   variable declared global  inside a
>   function, the reference will be
>   visible only inside the function. 
> You
>   can avoid this by using the `$GLOBALS`
>   array.

*And there is an example going with it.*

Trying to use [`$GLOBALS`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php) in your code, I have this portion of code :

```
$global_obj = null;
class my_class
{
   public $my_value;
   public function __construct()
   {
        $GLOBALS['global_obj'] = & $this;
   }
}
$a = new my_class;
$a->my_value = 5;

$global_obj->my_value = 10;
echo $a->my_value;
```

And I get the following output :

```
10
```

Which seems to work ;-)

If I replace the `__construct` method by this :

```
public function __construct()
{
    global $global_obj;
    $global_obj = & $this;
}
```

It doesn't work...

So it seems you should not use `global`, here, but `$GLOBALS`.

The explanation given in the manual is :

> Think about `global $var;` as a
>   shortcut to `$var =&
>   $GLOBALS['var'];`. 
> Thus assigning
>   another reference to `$var` only
>   changes the local variable's
>   reference.

---

*And, just so it's said : using global variables is generally not quite a good idea -- and, in this specific situation, it feels like a very bad idea...*

*(Now, if this question what just to understand why... Well, I can understand your curiosity ;-) )*

Comment: well, he gave you a pretty thorough explanation in his update. (+1)

Comment: Mr. Martin, this is from a certification practice test book. I don't need a correction. I need to know why it's 5, not 10. They can use a different wording to test my knowledge.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think I can do better than what I posted -- especially what I've added with my edit that points to the references sections of the manual : I think the explanation is precisely what I quoted from those pages *(the last quote in my answer should be the reason why your code is not working, I'd say)*

Comment: It's great! Accepted as answer! Thanks!

Comment: @Delirium why are you reading certification practice books for PHP4? This is not from Zend, is it?

Comment: @Delirium : you're welcomee :-) ;;; the question asked by Gordon is an interesting one, btw

Comment: I thought a newer edition didn't exist. It's from Zend. Do certifications work?

Comment: new feature! comments can be edited! :-) Mark even wrote a comment about a deleted comment...

Comment: There is a PHP 5 certification ( see http://www.zend.com/en/services/certification/php-5-certification/ ) ; in fact, I don't think the PHP 4 certification exists anymore, as PHP 4 has reached its end of life -- is not even maintained anymore for security-related stuff ! ;;; what do you mean *"do certifications work ?"* ; if you mean "do they help me get a job ?", well, not sure there is a definitive answer ^^